# Delete commit from pull request and branch in bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request

I accidentally committed my stash to my branch and it got included in the Pull request. My commits are:

```
ba5de90 -- Stash commit
f129038 -- final correct commit
```

I created a pull request including both the commits. Is there a way to delete the ba5de90 commit and remove it from the pull request? I tried `git stash drop` and it dropped the stash from my branch local. Not sure what next. any help?

Comment: remove the commit locally - with a `git reset HEAD^` and force push to your branch

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+last+commit+pull+request